# Get DbContext from DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext, dbset

I am developing some extensions methods to add some funcionalities for DbSet. However, when creating an "Update" method, I need the DbSet's DbContext to be able to modify the state of a entity. The current implementation:

```
public void Update<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> repository, TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        repository.Attach(entity);
        var context = // how get the context from repository?
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
    }
```

Does any one know how to get a DbContext from a DbSet instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get the DbContext from a DbSet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710769/can-you-get-the-dbcontext-from-a-dbset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a better way to accomplish that:

```
public static void MarkAsModified(this DbContext context, object entity)
    {
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```