# Entity Framework Core 2.0.1 Eager Loading on all nested related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, eager-loading

I have a simple problem, but cant seem to find a way around it. I am using Entity Framework Core version 2.0.1 and want to eager load all my entities by default.

Example:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

But when I load **Order** entity the related entity **Customer** and then inside it **Address** is null

What i have tried:

- Tried upgrading to version 2.1 and use LazyLoadingProxies set to false

This is just an example, I have entities with multiple nested levels and I want to load nested related data inside of a Generic Repository, so can't use **Include** and **ThenInclude** as I don't know the actual entity type when loading it.

Example:

```
    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
        if (predicate == null)
        {
            return await Context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }
        return await Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }
```

What am I missing? Is there something wrong I am doing in the repository? Any help or pointer towards a better design (if that's what the issue is here) are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So you set lazy loading to false, don't include the navigation properties and are wondering why the navigation properties aren't included? (what would be the point of `Include` if navigation properties were included by default anyhow)

Comment: Have tried marking my related properties as virtual and enabling lazy loading using proxies and also without proxies by injecting the lazy loader action in my entity constructor but to the same effect. Unless I manually use the Include and ThenInclude (which requires me to know the entity type) I can’t seem to get related data

Comment: You are asking for a feature which doesn't exist currently. As I recall, there are requests for something like this, but I don't know if and when it will be addressed.

Comment: Thanks for your input @IvanStoev. I thought they added a bunch of feature in the latest roll out of version 2.1.

Comment: @Jinish Unfortunately not this one :( Here is what I found - [Eager load all navigation properties #4851](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4851) (Closed), [Rule-based eager load (include) #2953](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2953) (Backlog), [Allow for declaring aggregates in the model (e.g. defining included properties or by some other means) #1985](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1985) (Backlog). Backlog means considered, but no concrete schedule.

Comment: Thanks for the references @IvanStoev. Much appreciated.

Comment: That's funny. My EFCore 2.0.2 by default eagerly loads every navigation property without me including them, and I'm looking for a way to turn it off. I haven't explicitly configured EFCore to do this. It just does it ouf of the box. Guess I'll try screwing around with the LazyLoadingProxies setting in order to solve my eager loading problem. Maybe you could try throwing LazyLoadingProxies overboard in order to turn it on.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Such feature officially does not exist currently (EF Core 2.0.2 and also the incoming 2.1). It's been requested in [Eager load all navigation properties #4851](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4851)(Closed) and currently is tracked by [Rule-based eager load (include) #2953](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2953) and [Allow for declaring aggregates in the model (e.g. defining included properties or by some other means) #1985](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1985) (both in Backlog, i.e. no concrete schedule).

I can offer the following two custom extension methods:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static partial class CustomExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<string> navigationPropertyPaths)
            where T : class
        {
            return navigationPropertyPaths.Aggregate(source, (query, path) => query.Include(path));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> GetIncludePaths(this DbContext context, Type clrEntityType, int maxDepth = int.MaxValue)
        {
            if (maxDepth < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxDepth));
            var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(clrEntityType);
            var includedNavigations = new HashSet<INavigation>();
            var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<INavigation>>();
            while (true)
            {
                var entityNavigations = new List<INavigation>();
                if (stack.Count <= maxDepth)
                {
                    foreach (var navigation in entityType.GetNavigations())
                    {
                        if (includedNavigations.Add(navigation))
                            entityNavigations.Add(navigation);
                    }
                }
                if (entityNavigations.Count == 0)
                {
                    if (stack.Count > 0)
                        yield return string.Join(".", stack.Reverse().Select(e => e.Current.Name));
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var navigation in entityNavigations)
                    {
                        var inverseNavigation = navigation.FindInverse();
                        if (inverseNavigation != null)
                            includedNavigations.Add(inverseNavigation);
                    }
                    stack.Push(entityNavigations.GetEnumerator());
                }
                while (stack.Count > 0 && !stack.Peek().MoveNext())
                    stack.Pop();
                if (stack.Count == 0) break;
                entityType = stack.Peek().Current.GetTargetType();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The first is just a convenient way of applying multiple string base `Include`.

The second does the actual job of collecting all `Include` paths for a type using EF Core provided metadata. It's basically directed cyclic graph processing starting with the passed entity type, excluding the inverse navigations of the included paths and emitting only the paths to "leaf" nodes.

The usage in your example could be like this:

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
{
    var query = Context.Set<T>()
        .Include(Context.GetIncludePaths(typeof(T));
    if (predicate != null)
        query = query.Where(predicate);
    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Sir, you deserve a medal 

Comment: You certainly do deserve a medal. This is an excellent sample! I am using it to help with my understanding of iterations as well as EF core. I was hoping though that you could **help me understand** how the `yield return` line works in your `GetIncludePaths` method. I don't quite understand what MSDN means when they say this: "Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called".

Comment: @Lopsided Space here is limited, but I'll try. This is called *iterator method*. The code inside does not execute until some external code start `foreach`-ing it. Once the external code enters `foreach`, your code starts executing. When it hits some `yield return` statement, it returns the next element to the caller. When the caller `foreach` needs the next item, your code resumes at the point after `yield return` and continues executing until it hits another `yield return` or ends. The whole process ends when your code ends or the caller exits `foreach` (with `break`, `return` or exception).

Comment: Oh my god. What?

Comment: This hurts me so much.

Comment: You are GOD like! Thanks so much!

Comment: This sucks so much. (I mean the lack of such feature in ef core 2.X... I'm currently bound to use it for a legacy project)

Comment: Genius! however, I needed to change the code a little bit for the new EF version. Instead of using `INavigation`, I had to use `IReadOnlyNavigation`.

Answer (score 8):

Ivan's answer is fantastic. I've adapted it slightly (using help from Chistoph's code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50864373/1636276)) just so the extension method can be chained off of the `DbContext` itself, in case others find that more convenient. For example, in my codebase I can write:

```cs
_commissionsContext.CommissionRulesetScopes.IncludeAll().ToListAsync();
```

And this will eagerly load the entire subgraph of entities for every `CommissionRulesetScope`:

```sql
SELECT [c].[CommissionPlanId], [c].[StartPeriod], [c].[CommissionRulesetId], [c0].[Id], [c0].[Name], [c1].[Id], [c1].[CsiScoreRuleId], [c1].[DealerOptionCommissionRuleId], [c1].[EmailCaptureRuleId], [c1].[ProductCommissionRuleId], [c1].[ProductConsistencyRuleId], [c1].[UnitCommissionRulesetId], [c2].[Id], [c2].[ConsecutiveFailurePenalty], [c2].[CurrentMonthPenalty], [c2].[Enabled], [c2].[Target], [d].[Id], [e].[Id], [e].[Enabled], [e].[Penalty], [e].[Target], [p].[Id], [p0].[Id], [p0].[CommissionBonus], [p0].[Enabled], [p0].[ProductTarget], [p0].[UnitTarget], [u].[Id], [u].[AverageCsiScoreRuleId], [u].[FinancePenetrationRuleId], [u].[GuaranteePeriodCommissionLevel], [u].[MinimumRequiredCsiReturnRate], [u].[MonthlyExpectationAttainmentRuleId], [u].[UnitCommissionTable], [a].[Id], [f].[Id], [m].[Id], [d0].[DealerOptionCommissionRuleId], [d0].[MinimumValue], [d0].[Commission], [t].[ProductCommissionRuleId], [t].[ProductTypeId], [t].[Commission], [t].[Id], [t].[Description], [t].[Key], [t0].[ProductConsistencyRuleId], [t0].[ProductMinMixRangeId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[ProductTypeId], [t0].[Id0], [t0].[Description], [t0].[Key], [t0].[ProductMinMixRangeId0], [t0].[MinimumUnitsTarget], [t0].[Target], [a0].[RuleId], [a0].[Target], [a0].[Points], [f0].[RuleId], [f0].[Target], [f0].[Points], [m0].[RuleId], [m0].[Target], [m0].[Points]
FROM [CommissionRulesetScope] AS [c]
INNER JOIN [CommissionPlan] AS [c0] ON [c].[CommissionPlanId] = [c0].[Id]
INNER JOIN [CommissionRuleset] AS [c1] ON [c].[CommissionRulesetId] = [c1].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [CsiScoreRule] AS [c2] ON [c1].[CsiScoreRuleId] = [c2].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [DealerOptionCommissionRule] AS [d] ON [c1].[DealerOptionCommissionRuleId] = [d].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [EmailCaptureRule] AS [e] ON [c1].[EmailCaptureRuleId] = [e].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [ProductCommissionRule] AS [p] ON [c1].[ProductCommissionRuleId] = [p].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [ProductConsistencyRule] AS [p0] ON [c1].[ProductConsistencyRuleId] = [p0].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [UnitCommissionRuleset] AS [u] ON [c1].[UnitCommissionRulesetId] = [u].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [AverageCsiScoreRule] AS [a] ON [u].[AverageCsiScoreRuleId] = [a].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [FinancePenetrationRule] AS [f] ON [u].[FinancePenetrationRuleId] = [f].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [MonthlyExpectationAttainmentRule] AS [m] ON [u].[MonthlyExpectationAttainmentRuleId] = [m].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [DealerOptionCommission] AS [d0] ON [d].[Id] = [d0].[DealerOptionCommissionRuleId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [p1].[ProductCommissionRuleId], [p1].[ProductTypeId], [p1].[Commission], [p2].[Id], [p2].[Description], [p2].[Key]
    FROM [ProductCommission] AS [p1]
    LEFT JOIN [ProductType] AS [p2] ON [p1].[ProductTypeId] = [p2].[Id]
) AS [t] ON [p].[Id] = [t].[ProductCommissionRuleId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [p3].[ProductConsistencyRuleId], [p3].[ProductMinMixRangeId], [p4].[Id], [p4].[ProductTypeId], [p5].[Id] AS [Id0], [p5].[Description], [p5].[Key], [p6].[ProductMinMixRangeId] AS [ProductMinMixRangeId0], [p6].[MinimumUnitsTarget], [p6].[Target]
    FROM [ProductMinMixRangeAssociation] AS [p3]
    INNER JOIN [ProductMinMixRange] AS [p4] ON [p3].[ProductMinMixRangeId] = [p4].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [ProductType] AS [p5] ON [p4].[ProductTypeId] = [p5].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN [ProductMinMixTarget] AS [p6] ON [p4].[Id] = [p6].[ProductMinMixRangeId]
) AS [t0] ON [p0].[Id] = [t0].[ProductConsistencyRuleId]
LEFT JOIN [AverageCsiScoreThreshold] AS [a0] ON [a].[Id] = [a0].[RuleId]
LEFT JOIN [FinancePenetrationThreshold] AS [f0] ON [f].[Id] = [f0].[RuleId]
LEFT JOIN [MonthlyExpectationAttainmentThreshold] AS [m0] ON [m].[Id] = [m0].[RuleId]
ORDER BY [c].[CommissionPlanId], [c].[StartPeriod], [c0].[Id], [c1].[Id], [d0].[DealerOptionCommissionRuleId], [d0].[MinimumValue], [t].[ProductCommissionRuleId], [t].[ProductTypeId], [t0].[ProductConsistencyRuleId], [t0].[ProductMinMixRangeId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[Id0], [t0].[ProductMinMixRangeId0], [t0].[MinimumUnitsTarget], [a0].[RuleId], [a0].[Target], [f0].[RuleId], [f0].[Target], [m0].[RuleId], [m0].[Target]
```

Here's the adaption:

```cs
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures that all navigation properties (up to a certain depth) are eagerly loaded when entities are resolved from this
    /// DbSet.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The queryable representation of this DbSet</returns>
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeAll<TEntity>(
        this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet,
        int maxDepth = int.MaxValue) where TEntity : class
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> result = dbSet;
        var context = dbSet.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>().Context;
        var includePaths = GetIncludePaths<TEntity>(context, maxDepth);

        foreach (var includePath in includePaths)
        {
            result = result.Include(includePath);
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <remarks>
    /// Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49597502/1636276
    /// </remarks>
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetIncludePaths<T>(DbContext context, int maxDepth = int.MaxValue)
    {
        if (maxDepth < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxDepth));

        var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
        var includedNavigations = new HashSet<INavigation>();
        var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<INavigation>>();

        while (true)
        {
            var entityNavigations = new List<INavigation>();

            if (stack.Count <= maxDepth)
            {
                foreach (var navigation in entityType.GetNavigations())
                {
                    if (includedNavigations.Add(navigation))
                        entityNavigations.Add(navigation);
                }
            }

            if (entityNavigations.Count == 0)
            {
                if (stack.Count > 0)
                    yield return string.Join(".", stack.Reverse().Select(e => e.Current!.Name));
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var navigation in entityNavigations)
                {
                    var inverseNavigation = navigation.FindInverse();
                    if (inverseNavigation != null)
                        includedNavigations.Add(inverseNavigation);
                }

                stack.Push(entityNavigations.GetEnumerator());
            }

            while (stack.Count > 0 && !stack.Peek().MoveNext())
                stack.Pop();

            if (stack.Count == 0)
                break;

            entityType = stack.Peek().Current!.GetTargetType();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.Include("Order.Customer.Address");`

Supports: .NET Core 3.1.8+ for sure, but I do not know if earlier as well

Comment: Please read the question well before answering. "so can't use Include..."

Answer (score 1):

The current "Ivan Stoev" accepted solution and "Tagc" answer are great. But it didn't work for me because I'm using TPT (Table Per Type) instead of TPH (Table Per Hierarchy).

So I made a little modification in the accepted solution that I share here just to help those who needs it. By the way, I think my solution should works in all cases, either for TPH, but I haven't thoroughly tested it.

I also replaced some Obsolete function usage.

Usage:

```
using (var ctx = Ctx.Get())
{
  _elecNets.AddRange(ctx.ElectricNetworks.IncludeAll().AsNoTracking());
}
```

Code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GeneralDb
{
    /// <summary>
    /// From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593482/entity-framework-core-2-0-1-eager-loading-on-all-nested-related-entities
    /// </summary>
    public static partial class EfCoreExtensions
    {
        /* Usage : 
         * 
         * 
         * 
                public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
                {
                    var query = Context.Set<T>().Include(Context.GetIncludePaths(typeof(T));
                    if (predicate != null)
                        query = query.Where(predicate);

                    return await query.ToListAsync();
                }
         * 
         * 
         */


        public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<string> navigationPropertyPaths) where T : class
        {
            return navigationPropertyPaths.Aggregate(source, (query, path) => query.Include(path));
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures that all navigation properties (up to a certain depth) are eagerly loaded when entities are resolved from this
        /// DbSet.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The queryable representation of this DbSet</returns>
        public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeAll<TEntity>(
            this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet,
            int maxDepth = int.MaxValue) where TEntity : class
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> result = dbSet;
            var context = dbSet.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>().Context;
            var includePaths = GetIncludePaths<TEntity>(context, maxDepth);

            foreach (var includePath in includePaths)
            {
                result = result.Include(includePath);
            }

            return result;
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <remarks>
        /// Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49597502/1636276
        /// 
        /// EO : Original code only works for TPH not TPT
        /// 
        /// </remarks>
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetIncludePaths<T>(this DbContext context, int maxDepth = int.MaxValue)
        {
            if (maxDepth < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxDepth));

            var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
            if (entityType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Unable to find the type: {typeof(T)} in the DbCOntext");
            }

            var includedNavigations = new HashSet<INavigation>();
            var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<INavigation>>();

            while (true)
            {
                var entityNavigations = new List<INavigation>();
                if (stack.Count <= maxDepth)
                {
                    foreach (INavigation navigation in entityType.GetNavigations())
                    {
                        if (includedNavigations.Add(navigation))
                            entityNavigations.Add(navigation);
                    }

                    // EO: Here for TPT (Table Per Type), we also need to retreive navigations from 
                    // derived class which have a corresponding <DBSet>
                    foreach (var entityTypeDerived in entityType.GetDerivedTypes())
                    {
                        foreach (INavigation navigation in entityTypeDerived.GetNavigations())
                        {
                            if (includedNavigations.Add(navigation))
                                entityNavigations.Add(navigation);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (entityNavigations.Count == 0)
                {
                    if (stack.Count > 0)
                        yield return string.Join(".", stack.Reverse().Select(e => e.Current.Name));
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var navigation in entityNavigations)
                    {
                        var inverseNavigation = navigation.Inverse;
                        if (inverseNavigation != null)
                            includedNavigations.Add(inverseNavigation);
                    }
                    stack.Push(entityNavigations.GetEnumerator());
                }
                while (stack.Count > 0 && !stack.Peek().MoveNext())
                    stack.Pop();
                if (stack.Count == 0) break;
                entityType = stack.Peek().Current.TargetEntityType;
            }
        }

        // ******************************************************************
    }
}
```