# Implicitly including all related data in a query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using ef-core 2.1, I have a generic abstract base class used for several similar entity types. Controllers inherit this class and invokes the protected methods with generic constraints, something like:

```
protected async Task<MyResult> GetBase<TEntity, TOut>(int? id)
    where TEntity : class, IFoo, IBar
    where TOut : class
{
    // Construct query.
    var query = id == null
        ? this.Context.Set<TEntity>()
        : this.Context.Set<TEntity>()
            .Where(p => p.Id == id);
    // ...
}
```

Not all entities share the same navigation properties, so simply extending the interface constraints such that multiple calls to `.Include()` would be valid is not possible. Does a means exist to generate a query that automatically includes all related data without explicitly declaring them?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593482/entity-framework-core-2-0-1-eager-loading-on-all-nested-related-entities/49597502#49597502

Comment: Your knowledge of ef and linq is incredible, that worked well, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, glad being in help :)