# How to save related data from another DbContext in EF Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have been trying to build a CMS using .NET Core 2.1 with a feature to stage web content changes, therefore I have three sites in my system architecture:

1. CMS Site - User could propose changes to web content through the CMS, and the changes will be pushed to the Staging/Production Site after being approved by admin.
2. Staging Frontend - The frontend web for internal UAT purposes, displays all approved/unapproved web content.
3. Production Frontend - The frontend web facing the public, displays only approved web content.

I have three `DbContext` instances injected for achieving the above:

1. `CmsContext` - Stores first-round web content changes proposed by a user.
2. `StagingContext` - Where the staging web frontend reads web content
3. `ProductionContext` - Where the production web frontend reads web content

The problem I encountered was, when I try to do the following (with lazy-loading enabled):

```
var entity = await stagingContext.FindAsync(entityType, entityId);
productionContext.Update(entity);
await productionContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

navigation properties are not updated as what I have expected.

I have also tried the `ChangeTracker.TrachGraph` approach, but it does not iterate through navigation properties.

I understand that the reason might be, even though lazy-loading is enabled, the navigation properties are never accessed before, so they are not filled up with values for `productionContext` to update.

I have read through the Microsoft Docs before I post this question, but could not figure out the correct way to do this. May I have your kind help on this guys? thanks

Comment: Why having separate DbContext? Do those contexts have a different database or you're doing it for "DDD bounded contexts"?

Comment: @Konrad The idea is like:
1. User proposes web content changes via the CMS, and the CMS saves these new content to `CmsContext`
2. Admin do a preliminary check on these changes, and push these to `StagingContext`, so that the Staging Frontend Web could display these proposed but not final-checked content.
3. Admin do a final check on these changes, and push these changes to 'ProductionContext', so that the Production Frontend Web could only show so-called 'launched and approved' changes.

Comment: So my problem is, I need to duplicate an entity and its related data from one context to another (`StagingContext` -> `CmsContext`), but when I do this using the codes above, related data are not saved to CmsContext.

Comment: `StagingContext` and `ProductionContext` are different databases that shares a same structure, while `CmsContext` has some more metadata than those.

Comment: You say that you use lazy loading but properties are never accessed before, so I think you have to eager load them with `Include`. You have to replace `FindAsync` call with `Include` to eager load all navigation properties you need, and then use `SingleOrDefaultAsync` or `SingleAsync`. Because properties are lazily loaded, they never get loaded because you never access them and EF Core has nothing to track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you use lazy loading but properties are never accessed before, so I think you have to eager load them with `Include`.

You have to replace `FindAsync` call with `Include` to eager load all navigation properties you need, and then use `SingleOrDefaultAsync` or `SingleAsync`. Because properties are lazily loaded, they never get loaded because you never access them and EF Core has nothing to track when you call `productionContext.Update(entity);`

I don't think calling `Update` accesses any properties for lazy loading to work, it just sets `EntityState`. I'm not sure if call to `SaveChangesAsync` change that. But if it doesn't work then it's possible that it's not lazily loaded.

If you just want to eager load everything you can take a look at [Entity Framework Core 2.0.1 Eager Loading on all nested related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593482/entity-framework-core-2-0-1-eager-loading-on-all-nested-related-entities)