# Translating generic eager load method from EF6 to EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

For EF6, I had a method in my generic repository that I exposed to all service layers in order to retrieve entities from the database with any nested properties as needed:

```
public IQueryable<T> OldMethod(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var queryable = set.AsQueryable();

    return includeProperties.Aggregate(queryable, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
}
```

This way, I could use the method in the following way:

```
var data = repo.OldMethod(x => x.Papers, => x.People.Select(y => y.Addresses)).ToList();
```

In EF6, this would load the `Papers` navigation property, the `People` navigation property, and the `Addresses` navigation property on each person. This, as expected, throws an exception in EFCore. Because of the switch to Include-->ThenInclude method in EFCore, I'm not quite sure how to easily replicate this at my service layer which I'd like to not require any information about EntityFramework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been asked many times since the initial release of EF Core. Earlier prerelease versions of EF Core even were supporting it, but then it has been removed from EF Core code (I guess in order to promote the new `Include` / `ThenInclude` pattern).

While `Include` / `ThenInclude` pattern looks more clear (besides the current Intellisense issues), it has one major drawback - requires access to `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions`, thus reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` assembly. While `params`Expression>` pattern has no such requirement.

The good thing is the one can relatively easily add that functionality. The EF6 source code is publicly available on GitHub, and from there we can see that it uses a method called [TryParsePath](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Internal/DbHelpers.cs#L260) to build dot separated string path which then is passed to the `string` overload of `Include` method.

The same can be applied in EF Core. We can probably use the EF6 code, but I'm going to provide my own version. It can be easily be seen that the supported constructs are member accessors or calls to method called `Select` with 2 arguments, the second being `LambdaExpression`.

Following is my interpretation of the above, encapsulated in two custom extension methods:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class IncludeExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<string> includePaths) where T : class
            => includePaths.Aggregate(source, (query, path) => query.Include(path));

        public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includePaths) where T : class
            => source.Include(includePaths.Select(e => GetIncludePath(e?.Body)));

        static string GetIncludePath(Expression source, bool allowParameter = false)
        {
            if (allowParameter && source is ParameterExpression)
                return null; // ok
            if (source is MemberExpression member)
                return CombinePaths(GetIncludePath(member.Expression, true), member.Member.Name);
            if (source is MethodCallExpression call && call.Method.Name == "Select"
                && call.Arguments.Count == 2 && call.Arguments[1] is LambdaExpression selector)
                return CombinePaths(GetIncludePath(call.Arguments[0]), GetIncludePath(selector.Body));
            throw new Exception("Invalid Include path.");
        }

        static string CombinePaths(string path1, string path2)
            => path1 != null ? path1 + "." + path2 : path2;
    }
}
```

The first is simply helper for calling multiple `string` includes (taken from my answer to [Entity Framework Core 2.0.1 Eager Loading on all nested related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593482/entity-framework-core-2-0-1-eager-loading-on-all-nested-related-entities/49597502#49597502)). The second is the method in question, which converts the expressions to strings and call the first. The main work is done by `GetIncludePath` private method which recursively processes the expression based on the aforementioned rules, plus one additional rule - when navigating bottom up, it should end with lambda parameter.

Now the implementation of the method is question is simple as that:

```
public IQueryable<T> OldMethod(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    => set.Include(includeProperties);
```

Answer (score 2):

When I first started using EFCore (switching from EF6), I built these extension methods to translate the "old" way of including `x => x.People.Select(y => y.Addresses)` to strings like `"People.Addresses"`, which are supported by EFCore too;

```
public static class Extensions
{

    private class ReferencedPropertyFinder : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly Type _ownerType;
        private readonly List<PropertyInfo> _properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
        private Expression _parameterExpression;
        private int _currentPosition = 0;

        public ReferencedPropertyFinder(Type ownerType)
        {
            _ownerType = ownerType;
        }

        public IReadOnlyList<PropertyInfo> Properties
        {
            get { return _properties; }
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {

            var propertyInfo = node.Member as PropertyInfo;
            if (propertyInfo != null) {
                var currentParameter = GetParameter(node);

                if (_parameterExpression == currentParameter) {
                    _properties.Insert(_currentPosition, propertyInfo);
                } else {
                    _properties.Add(propertyInfo);
                    _parameterExpression = currentParameter;
                    _currentPosition = _properties.Count() - 1;
                }

            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }

        private ParameterExpression GetParameter(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Expression is ParameterExpression) {
                return (ParameterExpression)node.Expression;
            } else {
                return GetParameter((MemberExpression)node.Expression);
            }
        }


    }


    private static IReadOnlyList<PropertyInfo> GetReferencedProperties<T, U>(this Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
    {
        var v = new ReferencedPropertyFinder(typeof(T));
        v.Visit(expression);
        return v.Properties;
    }

    public static string ToPropertyPath<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var properties = expression.GetReferencedProperties();
        var path = string.Join(".", properties.Select(x => x.Name));
        return path;
    }

}
```

Incorporating these in your code, you could say something like:

```
public IQueryable<T> OldMethod(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var queryable = set.AsQueryable();

    return includeProperties.Aggregate(queryable, (current, includeProperty) => 
        current.Include(includeProperty.ToPropertyPath()));
}
```

Comment: You answered first, and that gave me the information I used in order to make the changes I wanted so you get the bounty. I just feel like the second answer gave a bit better detail which can help future readers. Hope I'm doing this right..