# How to implement ThenInclude into EF Core custom specification?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

EF Core 3.1
I have seen [Specification](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-query-specification) example, and want to implement ThenInclude pattern.

```
public static class QuerySpecificationExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Specify<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, ISpecification<T> spec) where T : class
    {
        // fetch a Queryable that includes all expression-based includes
        var queryableResultWithIncludes = spec.Includes
            .Aggregate(query,
                (current, include) => current.Include(include));

        // modify the IQueryable to include any string-based include statements
        var secondaryResult = spec.IncludeStrings
            .Aggregate(queryableResultWithIncludes,
                (current, include) => current.Include(include));

        // return the result of the query using the specification's criteria expression
        return secondaryResult.Where(spec.Criteria);
    }
}
```

I can add this into string for example "User.UserRole.Role", but I want to implement object. 
Maybe there it is not possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Includes` member of the aforementioned `ISpecification<T>` is declared as

```
List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> Includes { get; }
```

The problem is that EF Core `Include` / `ThenInclude` chain cannot be represented with `Expression<Func<T, object>>`. This pattern was used in EF6 which supported a special syntax (`Select`) inside the include expression to resolve collection element. But EF Core does not support that out of the box.

The easiest and most natural way to plug EF Core pattern is to change the definition as follows:

```
List<Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>>> Includes { get; }
```

Adding the sample for entity having `User` property having `UserRoles` collection having `Role` property would be like this:

```
Includes.Add(q => q.Include(e => e.User).ThenInclude(e => e.UserRoles).ThenInclude(e => e.Role));
```

And the corresponding part of the `Specify` method implementation would be:

```
var queryableResultWithIncludes = spec.Includes
    .Aggregate(query,
        (current, include) => include(current));
```

Comment: Nice approach. The only issue I see with this is the `IIncludableQueryable` interface will introduce a dependency to EF core. This will be an issue in a DDD situation where the domain shouldn't know much about EF core internals.

Comment: @GETah True. But that's what is given to us by EF Core. I guess they find the `Include` / `ThenInclude` more intuitive, also supporting filtered, ordered etc. includes, something not possible with `params Expression<Func<...>>` approach. And they do not care much about DDD purity (and they shouldn't - EF Core entities represent *data model*, which doesn't care about encapsulation, business logic and similar OOP). Anyway, I have this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997082/translating-generic-eager-load-method-from-ef6-to-ef-core/53053633#53053633 in case EF6 style is enough for you.

Comment: I actually found a nice way around by specifying includes as string parameters. Using `nameof(_property_to_include_)` solves the problem in a nice way.

Comment: @GETah Ha, nice only if you have single level.  In which case the original pattern with `params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` works. The problem is with nested (`ThenInclude`) things, and especially with collections. Try expressing "Products.Orders.OrderDetails" with interpolated string and `nameof` and you'll see.

Comment: `ThenInclude` can be covered by string includes as well :) So you can perform things like `"${nameof(Blog)},{nameof(Blog).nameof(Post)}` which is equivalent to .Include(b => b.blog).ThenInclude(b => b.Post) - I haven't compiled this though :p