# EF Core getting inverse navigation property from metadata

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, system.reflection

Consider the following setup with models `TodoItem` and `Person`

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<TodoItem>()
    .HasOne(t => t.Assignee)
    // for simplicity lets assume a Person is assigned to only TodoItem
    .WithOne(p => p.AssignedItem)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.AssigneeId);

modelBuilder.Entity<TodoItem>()
    .HasOne(t => t.Reviewer)
    .WithOne(p => p.ReviewItem) 
    // for simplicity lets assume a Person owns only one TodoItem
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.ReviewerId);
```

reflectively, probably using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata`, how can I figure out that

- the property `TodoItem.Assignee` (as configured in `HasOne( ... )` ) is associated with the "inverse navigation property" `Person.AssignedItem` (as configured in in `WithOne( ... )`
- and similarly, the property `TodoItem.Reviewer` is "inversely related" to `Person.ReviewItem`

I guess I'm trying to figure out how to access the configuration set in the `modelBuilder.Hasxxx( ... ) and modelBuilder.Withxxx( ... )` methods.

I need this because I'm reflectively traversing through a query result set of a nested data structure and need to ensure that my algorithm is forward looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigations in the EF Core metadata are represented by [INavigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.inavigation?view=efcore-2.1) interface. They can be obtained from [IEntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ientitytype?view=efcore-2.1) using [GetNavigations](https://learn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitytypeextensions.getnavigations?view=efcore-2.1) or [FindNavigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitytypeextensions.findnavigation?view=efcore-2.1) extension methods.

Once you have `INavigation`, the inverse navigation (if exists) can be obtained with [FindInverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.navigationextensions.findinverse?view=efcore-2.1) extension method.

You can see sample navigation traversal in my answer to  [Entity Framework Core 2.0.1 Eager Loading on all nested related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593482/entity-framework-core-2-0-1-eager-loading-on-all-nested-related-entities/49597502#comment98182773_49597502).