# ASP.NET Web API : query selecting records bring attached tables data also

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

We are selecting records from a table `AdditionalDetail`; this works fine, but it returns data for `FullDetails` also, which is another model.

How to get records from `AdditionalDetailAbstract` model only? I want to update say `AmountPaid`, with small amount of rows it's not an issue, but in a big list of data, it's a performance issue.

We are using ASP.NET Web API.

```
var additionalData = dbContext.AdditionalDetail 
                              .Where(c => c.AdditionalDetailId == 525 && c.CompanyId == 15)
                              .FirstOrDefault();

public abstract class AdditionalDetailAbstract
{
    [Key]
    public long AdditionalDetailId { get; set; }
    public long DetailsId { get; set; }
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountToBePay { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
}

public class AdditionalDetail : AdditionalDetailAbstract
{
    public CaseDetail FullDetails { get; set; }
}
```

How to deal with it? So I can update only `AdditionalDetailAbstract` model data.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, If you want to select data from `AdditionalDetail` but only want to select properties from `AdditionalDetailAbstract`, you can try this code:

```
var reuslt = _dbcontext.AdditionalDetailAbstract.Where(c => c.AdditionalDetailId == 2 && c.CompanyId == 15)
                .Select(c => new AdditionalDetailAbstract
                {
                    AdditionalDetailId = c.AdditionalDetailId,
                    DetailsId = c.DetailsId,
                    CompanyId = c.CompanyId,
                    AmountToBePay = c.AmountToBePay,
                    AmountPaid = c.AmountPaid
                })
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

in this code ef core will not select data from related model

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually if "LazyLoadingEnabled" is enabled then it will bring all related model data, which will effect performance.

[Disable Lazy Loading in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56301656/disable-lazy-loading-in-entity-framework-core)

```
ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```