# Asp.net core how to loading related data in viewmodel Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on a `Asp.net core 2.2` project and have a problem about loading related data in ViewModel.

First of all i have a table named `QuestionTbl` :

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int questionID { get; set; }
    public string questionTitle { get; set; }
    public string GroupID { get; set; }
}
```

As you see i have a `string` property called `GroupID` in `Question` table that shows groups of each question.

**For Example**

```
1 row in questionTbl
---------
questionID = 1
questionTitle = 'What is Your Name ?'
GroupID = '3,4,5'
```

In the example above question with `ID = 1` is in 3 groups `(3 and 4 and 5)`.

And `GroupTbl` :

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to show list of question with related groups.

I have a `ViewModel` like this :

```
public class GetQuestionViewModel
{
    public int questionID { get; set; }
    public string questionTitle { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> QuestionGroups { get; set; }
}
```

And my entity framework query :

```
var questionQuery = (from a in _db.QuestionTbl
                             select new GetQuestionViewModel()
                             {
                                 questionID = a.questionID,
                                 questionTitle = a.questionTitle
                             })
                             .Include(q => q.QuestionGroups)
                             .ToList();
```

I want to have a list contains questions and groups of each question. But `QuestionGroups` returns null in my query. I also read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) link but it did not help me.

Comment: Your tables are not normalized, and thus your `Include` will not work in EF Core. I would highly recommend you change your models so that they are.

Comment: @chakeda Thank you. I think I should change the structure of the tables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Core 2.0.1 Eager Loading on all nested related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593482/entity-framework-core-2-0-1-eager-loading-on-all-nested-related-entities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not use `Include` here for a viewModel directly.I advice that you could use [many-to-many relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) for your Question and Group models.

Models:

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int questionID { get; set; }
    public string questionTitle { get; set; }

    public List<QuestionGroup> QuestionGroups { get; set; }
    //public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    //public string GroupID { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public List<QuestionGroup> QuestionGroups { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionGroup
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class GetQuestionViewModel
{
    public int questionID { get; set; }
    public string questionTitle { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> QuestionGroups { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext;

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionGroup>()
       .HasKey(t => new { t.QuestionId, t.GroupId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionGroup>()
            .HasOne(qg => qg.Question)
            .WithMany(q => q.QuestionGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(qg => qg.QuestionId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionGroup>()
            .HasOne(qg=>qg.Group)
            .WithMany(g => g.QuestionGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(qg => qg.GroupId);
   }
```

EF Core query;

```
var questionQuery = (from a in _context.QuestionTbl.Include(q => q.QuestionGroups)
                             select new GetQuestionViewModel()
                             {
                                 questionID = a.questionID,
                                 questionTitle = a.questionTitle,
                                 QuestionGroups = a.QuestionGroups.Select(qg => qg.Group).ToList()

                             })
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your tables, following the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/fk-constraints):

**Question**:

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int questionID { get; set; }
    public string questionTitle { get; set; }

    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Group_ID")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

**Group**:

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Question> questions { get; set; }
}
```

At this point you can query the records like so:

```
db.Question.Include(q => q.Group)
```