# One to one relation with only one navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relationship

I have a database table which is referenced in different tables. The relation is a one to one.

Assuming I have three database tables:

**Detail** with one field **DetailId** 
**Foo** with the fields **FooId** and **DetailId**
**Bar** with the field **BarId** and **DetailId**

My models would look like this

```
public class Detail
{
    public int DetailId { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int DetailId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Detail Detail { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int DetailId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Detail Detail { get; set; }
}
```

And in my Configuration I have

```
public class BarConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Bar>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Bar> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(b => b.Detail)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Bar>(x => x.DetailId);
    }
}
```

**My problem is:** When I load an object of Bar my DetailId is set to the correct value but my Detail property is null.

My `BarConfiguration` is called in my context in `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`.

Comment: Have you used eager loading or explicit loading for the dependent entity?

Comment: I just tryed it with eager loading and then it's working. 
Is there an option without using Include?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593482/entity-framework-core-2-0-1-eager-loading-on-all-nested-related-entities