# EF Core GetNavigations ignoring a collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following structure:

```
public class Message
{
    ...
    public MessageType MessageType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> ProductsWhereThisIsDefaultCompletedSale { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    ...
    public Guid? DefaultCompletedSaleMessageId { get; set; }
    public Message DefaultCompletedSaleMessage { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public MessageType {...}
```

And the mapper:

```
EntityTypeBuilder<Product> entityBuilder;
entityBuilder
    .HasMany(p => p.Messages)
    .WithMany(m => m.Products);
entityBuilder
    .HasOne(p => p.DefaultCompletedSaleMessage)
    .WithMany(m => m.ProductsWhereThisIsDefaultCompletedSale)
    .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

And this is working nicely with the database (at least I think so...). When I add a new product to the `Messages` collection it's added to the `ProductsMessages` relationships' table. The records are loaded when I eager load them (Include(...)).

The problem is, I'm trying to get all navigation properties to auto include them on certain specific scenarios. But that's not working properly. When I run `entityType.GetNavigations()` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitytypeextensions.getnavigations?view=efcore-5.0)) on Message it doesn't return `Products`, it only returns the other two navigation properties, `ProductsWhereThisIsDefaultCompletedSale` and `MessageType`:

[image]

Any ideas on what am I doing incorrectly?

Please let me know if you need more information. I'm on .NET5. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because these are the so called *skip navigations*, introduced in EF Core 5.0 and used for implementing many-to-many with implicit join entity.

They are represented by [ISkipNavigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iskipnavigation?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ISkipNavigation);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0) interface, which for some design decision does not inherit [INavigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.inavigation?view=efcore-5.0) interface returned by the `GetNavigations` method, so they are retrieved with separate method called [`GetSkipNavigations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ientitytype.getskipnavigations?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType.GetSkipNavigations);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0).

But both `INavigation` and `ISkipNavigation` share a common interface [`INavigationBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.inavigationbase?view=efcore-5.0), so if its properties/methods are enough for what are you trying to do with them, you can get both type of collection navigations with something like this (needs `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;`):

```
var allNavigations = entityType.GetNavigations()
    .Concat<INavigationBase>(entityType.GetSkipNavigations());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ivan. Going to test it right away.

Comment: Ivan, thank you, it did work. But, now I'm getting a timeout error... Maybe I'm trying to load too many properties? `"Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."` I'm trying to eager load all relationships for specific entities. I'm using most of the code you posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593482/entity-framework-core-2-0-1-eager-loading-on-all-nested-related-entities  
I thought it could also be related to circular dependency, but the the breaks during the include, not while getting the prop

Comment: @eestein Starting from EFC 3.0, loading many collections is highly inefficient. Try combining it with EFC 5.0 + [Split queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries), e.g. `source.AsSplitQuery()` and then all these includes, and see how it goes.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much :) Are you part of the EFCore team? Just wondering because of all your answers... as a 3rd question :D would this AsSplitQuery be considered not recommended? I'm trying to get eager loading done, but I don't wanna write something that will break in the future or create future problems. Is it safe for me to use it like that?

Comment: I'm not participating in that project. Not even using it in my projects, just more like free time hobby :-) As of split queries, they were used internally in pre v3 versions of EFC, then in v3 they decided to switch to "single query" mode, which then caused a lot of troubles, so in v5 they brought back the pre v3 functionality, but with option. The documentation link shows pros/cons of both solutions, so you have to choose. But slow is basically "not working", so you don't seem to have a real option.  Using split mode should be safe as it is officially introduced new old feature :-)

Comment: Sir, you just saved my day. Thanks!