# EF Core exception : Npgsql.PostgreException: '42703' Column c1.Index does not exist

Tags: c#, postgresql, exception, logging, entity-framework-core

Using EFCore 6.0.8 in a .net 6 project.

I receive an Exception: Npgsql.PostgreException: '42703' Column c1.Index does not exist when I try to load a hierarchy of classes.

I know I do not have any table named 'c1' and I don't think I have a column 'Index' anywhere in my code.

Note: After verification I had a column "Index" in a class persisted by EF Core.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, OK. IO added the EFCore version. I showed the generated SQL in the answer because that is exactly the essence of my question. I took the time to post the question and answer it althought I already had the answer in order to help peoples. I lost many hours on that. I just want to help. I wonder is that you who put a -1 on the question? I hope you will never get into the same problem, search the solution and fall on this post ... Anyway you were right, specifying EFCore version is a good idea.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, It is not a bug and I never pretend it was one. Thats is 100% normal. I only wanted to bring to light the way to find what is the source of that alias used and what it correspond to. Tracing is the way to find the proble very quickly. Have you read everything? Is there anything that is not clear?

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. To find it, I configure the `DbContext` to trace SQL command. Then I executed the command (the one constructed by EF Core) directly in DBeaver (any SQL tool could do the job).

For query with link to other tables, EF Core use many aliases to make SQL "join" clause (for relations). Those aliases are made of one letter first, but after they are one letter+digits. To discover those aliases, we have to trace the request made by EF Core to the database. In my case (see below) the table "c1" was an alias used to join tables.

This is the start of my `OnConfiguring` of my `DbContext` where I setup "Query tracing":

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

    // Trace => Most detailed information
    optionsBuilder.LogTo(DbLogger.WriteLine, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
    ...
```

And my logger:

```
    public class DbLogger
    {
        public Log Log { get; }

        private DbLogger()
        {
            Log = new Log(null, false, null);
            Log.Name = "Ef Core";
            Log.IsAutoSaveOnChange = false;
            Log.IsAutoSaveOnExit = false;
        }

        public static DbLogger Instance { get; } = new DbLogger();

        public static void WriteLine(string ? msg)
        {
            Instance.Log.AddEntry(LogLevel.LogMessage, msg);

#if DEBUG
            Debug.WriteLine($"Database logging: {msg}");
#endif
        }
    }
```

This is the result of tracing EF Core. This is the query where I could have found my bug (the Index added field). I do not add the code of the linq query because it is part of a generic query (this is the link to what I use to build the query: [Entity Framework Core 2.0.1 Eager Loading on all nested related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593482/entity-framework-core-2-0-1-eager-loading-on-all-nested-related-entities/73506044#73506044))

```
  SELECT e."ElectricNetworkId", e."EfficiencyCurveFormula", e."Name", t1."ResourceId", t1."CommConfigId", t1."ElectricNetworkId", t1."Name", t1."GenerationPowerMax", t1."GenerationPowerMin", t1."TimeToCooldown", t1."TimeToStartToFullPower", t1."ActualCapacity", t1."StorageCapacity", t1."MaximumPower", t1."SetPoint", t1."Discriminator", t1."CommConfigId0", t1."CommunicationProtocolType", t1."ResourceId0", t1."Index", t1."IpAddress", t1."Port", t1."Discriminator0", t1."Dnp3PropertyBaseId", t1."CommConfigDnp3Id", t1."Description", t1."Index0", t1."Name0", t1."PropertyName", t1."InputOffset", t1."InputScale", t1."IsPersistent", t1."Offset", t1."OutputControl", t1."Scale", t1."SelectRequired", t1."SmpDeadBand", t1."Unit", t1."UnitMultiplier", t1."InputOffset0", t1."InputScale0", t1."Offset0", t1."OutputControl0", t1."Scale0", t1."SelectRequired0", t1."SmpDeadBand0", t1."Unit0", t1."UnitMultiplier0", t1."Discriminator1"
  FROM "ElectricNetwork" AS e
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT r."ResourceId", r."CommConfigId", r."ElectricNetworkId", r."Name", r0."GenerationPowerMax", r0."GenerationPowerMin", r0."TimeToCooldown", r0."TimeToStartToFullPower", r2."ActualCapacity", r2."StorageCapacity", c."MaximumPower", c."SetPoint", CASE
          WHEN (s."ResourceId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'GazTurbineReadOnly'
          WHEN (b0."ResourceId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Battery'
          WHEN (w1."ResourceId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'WaterHeater'
          WHEN (c."ResourceId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'ControllableLoad'
          WHEN (w0."ResourceId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'WindTurbine'
          WHEN (w."ResourceId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'WaterTurbine'
          WHEN (g."ResourceId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'GazTurbine'
          WHEN (b."ResourceId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Biomass'
      END AS "Discriminator", t."CommConfigId" AS "CommConfigId0", t."CommunicationProtocolType", t."ResourceId" AS "ResourceId0", t."Index", t."IpAddress", t."Port", t."Discriminator" AS "Discriminator0", t0."Dnp3PropertyBaseId", t0."CommConfigDnp3Id", t0."Description", t0."Index" AS "Index0", t0."Name" AS "Name0", t0."PropertyName", t0."InputOffset", t0."InputScale", t0."IsPersistent", t0."Offset", t0."OutputControl", t0."Scale", t0."SelectRequired", t0."SmpDeadBand", t0."Unit", t0."UnitMultiplier", t0."InputOffset0", t0."InputScale0", t0."Offset0", t0."OutputControl0", t0."Scale0", t0."SelectRequired0", t0."SmpDeadBand0", t0."Unit0", t0."UnitMultiplier0", t0."Discriminator" AS "Discriminator1"
      FROM "Resource" AS r
      LEFT JOIN "ResourceGenerator" AS r0 ON r."ResourceId" = r0."ResourceId"
      LEFT JOIN "ResourceStorage" AS r2 ON r."ResourceId" = r2."ResourceId"
      LEFT JOIN "Biomass" AS b ON r."ResourceId" = b."ResourceId"
      LEFT JOIN "GazTurbine" AS g ON r."ResourceId" = g."ResourceId"
      LEFT JOIN "WaterTurbine" AS w ON r."ResourceId" = w."ResourceId"
      LEFT JOIN "WindTurbine" AS w0 ON r."ResourceId" = w0."ResourceId"
      LEFT JOIN "ControllableLoad" AS c ON r."ResourceId" = c."ResourceId"
      LEFT JOIN "WaterHeater" AS w1 ON r."ResourceId" = w1."ResourceId"
      LEFT JOIN "Battery" AS b0 ON r."ResourceId" = b0."ResourceId"
      LEFT JOIN "StorageTestReadOnly" AS s ON r."ResourceId" = s."ResourceId"
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT c0."CommConfigId", c0."CommunicationProtocolType", c0."ResourceId", c1."Index", c1."IpAddress", c1."Port", CASE
              WHEN (c1."CommConfigId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'CommConfigDnp3'
          END AS "Discriminator"
          FROM "CommConfig" AS c0
          LEFT JOIN "CommConfigDnp3" AS c1 ON c0."CommConfigId" = c1."CommConfigId"
      ) AS t ON r."ResourceId" = t."ResourceId"
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT d."Dnp3PropertyBaseId", d."CommConfigDnp3Id", d."Description", d."Index", d."Name", d."PropertyName", d0."InputOffset", d0."InputScale", d0."IsPersistent", d0."Offset", d0."OutputControl", d0."Scale", d0."SelectRequired", d0."SmpDeadBand", d0."Unit", d0."UnitMultiplier", d2."InputOffset" AS "InputOffset0", d2."InputScale" AS "InputScale0", d2."Offset" AS "Offset0", d2."OutputControl" AS "OutputControl0", d2."Scale" AS "Scale0", d2."SelectRequired" AS "SelectRequired0", d2."SmpDeadBand" AS "SmpDeadBand0", d2."Unit" AS "Unit0", d2."UnitMultiplier" AS "UnitMultiplier0", CASE
              WHEN (d3."Dnp3PropertyBaseId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Dnp3OutputBinary'
              WHEN (d2."Dnp3PropertyBaseId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Dnp3OutputAnalog'
              WHEN (d1."Dnp3PropertyBaseId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Dnp3InputBinary'
              WHEN (d0."Dnp3PropertyBaseId" IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Dnp3InputAnalog'
          END AS "Discriminator"
          FROM "Dnp3PropertyBase" AS d
          LEFT JOIN "Dnp3InputAnalog" AS d0 ON d."Dnp3PropertyBaseId" = d0."Dnp3PropertyBaseId"
          LEFT JOIN "Dnp3InputBinary" AS d1 ON d."Dnp3PropertyBaseId" = d1."Dnp3PropertyBaseId"
          LEFT JOIN "Dnp3OutputAnalog" AS d2 ON d."Dnp3PropertyBaseId" = d2."Dnp3PropertyBaseId"
          LEFT JOIN "Dnp3OutputBinary" AS d3 ON d."Dnp3PropertyBaseId" = d3."Dnp3PropertyBaseId"
      ) AS t0 ON t."CommConfigId" = t0."CommConfigDnp3Id"
  ) AS t1 ON e."ElectricNetworkId" = t1."ElectricNetworkId"
  ORDER BY e."ElectricNetworkId", t1."ResourceId", t1."CommConfigId0"
```